# Is the Simplex Method weaker than other methods?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method, two-phase-simplex

Given linear program:
$$ \text{min } x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3  $$
s.t.:
$$ -3x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4 $$
$$ x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 3 $$
$$ x_i \geq 0; i = \{1,2,3\} $$

a solution by simplex method (with double pass) is not possible, because pivot column is negative. However Matlab's $\texttt{linprog}$ function gives me nice looking solution:

```
linprog(c,[],[],A,b,zeros(1,length(c)))
```

$$ x=(0,\ 0.5,\ 3.5) $$
$$ fval = 6.5 $$

Is it because simplex method is **weaker** than method that matlab uses? Is set of programmes that can be solved by simplex smaller than set of programmes by other methods?

Comment: No, this program *is* solvable with the simplex method, and actually at the end of phase 1 one obtains $(0,0.5,3.5)$. And more generally the simplex method solves all linear programs, it is not weaker than, say, the ellipsoid method.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, i have overlooked that. How is it possible that simplex method ended with result even when A has no standard basis in it?

Comment: Is $A$ the program you described? If you are familiar with the two-phase simplex, then taking ($x_1,x_2,x_3,t_1,t_2$) as variables in the first phase, you can use $t_1,t_2$ as a starting basis with values $(4,3)$.

Comment: @Filip: Try http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html, it will give you the Tableau and converges to your soultion with no changes to the specifications. Regards

Answer (score 4):

At the time when this question was asked (around December $2013$), the $\texttt{linprog}$ MatLab function actually used the Revised Simplex method (with two-phase and dual) to solve linear models given to it. This is supported by the [past documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130219040606/http://www.mathworks.com:80/help/optim/ug/linprog.html;jsessionid=0a1430cafb878fca79fc703701de) in which the methods and references are those for the mentioned algorithm. This is why $\texttt{linprog}$ is able to find the correct solution of $x^T=(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2})$ with the objective function output of $\frac{13}{2}$. Thus, the Simplex Method is not weaker than other methods compared to $\texttt{linprog}$ as the function actually uses the Simplex method itself. $[1]$

$$$$
Back to the original model, the model provided is able to be solved via the Two-Phase or Big-M approach. For simplicity sake, lets solve this model by hand using the Big-M approach. Thus, let’s standardize the model as such:

$$\min\quad z-x_1+x_2-2x_3-M(a_1+a_2)=0$$
$$\text{Subject to: }\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$
$$-3x_1+x_2+x_3+a_1=4$$
$$x_1-x_2+x_3+a_2=3$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3,a_1,a_2\ge0$$

With $M$ being the “largest” number in $\Bbb R$.

This would look like the following in the initial tableau:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & a_2 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -1 & 1 & -2 & -M & -M & 0 & - \\
       ? & 0 & -3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 4 & - \\
       ? & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 3 & - \\ \hline
\end{array}

After solving for our basic variables:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & a_2 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -2M-1 &  1 & 2M-2 & 0 & 0 & 7M & - \\
     a_1 & 0 &    -3 &  1 &    1 & 1 & 0 &  4 & 4 \\
     a_2 & 0 &     1 & -1 &    1 & 0 & 1 &  3 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{array}

After pivoting the $x_3$ column with the $a_2$ row we get:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & a_2 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -4M+1 &  2M-1 & 0 & 0 & -2M+2 & M+6 & - \\
     a_1 & 0 &    -4 &     2 & 0 & 1 &    -1 &  1 & 1/2 \\
     x_3 & 0 &     1 &    -1 & 1 & 0 &     1 &  3 & \infty \\ \hline
\end{array}

Pivoting the $x_2$ column with the $a_1$ row we get:

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline BV & z & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & a_1 & a_2 & RHS & RT \\
\hline z & 1 & -1 &  0 & 0 & -M+\frac{1}{2} & -M+\frac{3}{2} & \frac{13}{2} & - \\
     x_2 & 0 & -2 &  1 & 0 &    \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2} & - \\
     x_3 & 0 & -1 &  0 & 1 &    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{2} & - \\ \hline
\end{array}

Which is our final tableau with:

$$x^*_1=0$$
$$x^*_2=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x^*_3=\frac{7}{2}$$
$$z^*=\frac{13}{2}$$

Which is exactly what MatLab’s $\texttt{linprog}$ function got.

---

$[1]$ As of the year $2022$, there are current solvers that are generally better than most the most of the basic solvers used in the past (in the $2013$ era), like the open-source [HiGHS solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiGHS_optimization_solver), or the closed source [CPLEX solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPLEX). They use various optimization techniques that build upon the simplex-method that makes the algorithmic process much faster, but done at a more nuanced level.